# "To Sphere" option not working

Tags: mesh

I'm taking an online Blender course and the instructor is using the "To Sphere" option to make the holes for a bowling ball made from an icosphere. So for the picture here I insetted the edges, subdivided by 3, then tried "To Sphere" but nothing happened. Does anyone know how to fix this?[image]

Comment: Showing perhaps a [gif](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers) containing the exact steps you are taking would help understand the issue you are having. This seems to work fine here.

Comment: To sphere operator has a "factor" (0 to 1, 1 is the most spherical possible) which can be set moving the mouse or in the operator panel after the operator is confirmed.

Comment: Or use LoopTools addon, Specials menu (W) > LoopTools > Circle

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this:

[image]

of course you have to **drag** the "to sphere" command action to get the desired amount (1 = maximum effect)

Answer (score 2):

The 'To Sphere' tool on selected vertices is tricky to use because you have to move the mouse and not every direction results in a change.

When you use the tool, moving the mouse left **enough** will diminish the effect, moving the mouse right **enough**, it will turn into a sphere.

In most cases, you'll probably want the full force, a clean circle. Then numeric input is your friend. Just use the tool and don't bother using the mouse. Hit <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>RETURN</kbd>. That is a safe way to use the tool.